# Webrick or Puma, random 500 errors with no log. Is there a better log

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my app is crashing randomly in development.

I start using Puma, sometimes on page request it crash.
No log, only a generic error 500.

Now I switch to Webrick, the same.

```
CACHE Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "product_relations" ON "products"."id" = "product_relations"."product_id" WHERE "product_relations"."productable_id" = $1 AND "product_relations"."productable_type" = $2 AND "products"."state" = $3 AND "products"."published_at" <= '2020-05-04 20:52:34.630525' ORDER BY "products"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $4  [["productable_id", 34969], ["productable_type", "Content"], ["state", "active"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  CACHE Brand Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" INNER JOIN "content_brands" ON "brands"."id" = "content_brands"."brand_id" WHERE "content_brands"."content_id" = $1 ORDER BY "brands"."name" ASC LIMIT $2  [["content_id", 34969], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  CACHE Product Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "product_relations" ON "products"."id" = "product_relations"."product_id" WHERE "product_relations"."productable_id" = $1 AND "product_relations"."productable_type" = $2 AND "products"."state" = $3 AND "products"."published_at" <= '2020-05-04 20:52:34.630525' ORDER BY "products"."published_at" DESC LIMIT $4  [["productable_id", 34969], ["productable_type", "Content"], ["state", "active"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  CACHE Brand Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "brands".* FROM "brands" INNER JOIN "content_brands" ON "brands"."id" = "content_brands"."brand_id" WHERE "content_brands"."content_id" = $1 ORDER BY "brands"."name" ASC LIMIT $2  [["content_id", 34969], ["LIMIT", 11]]
  Rendered app/cells/product_reviews/show.html.haml (Duration: 77.6ms | Allocations: 31933)
  Rendered contents/review.html.haml within layouts/application (Duration: 184.7ms | Allocations: 109291)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 233ms (ActiveRecord: 23.7ms | Allocations: 140545)
```

I need to reboot the server, and then the page load. 
No error, only a generic **Completed 500 Internal Server Error**

I have in my development.rb

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

and

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

Is there a deeper log???

Comment: "The available log levels are: :debug, :info, :warn, :error, :fatal, and :unknown, corresponding to the log level numbers from 0 up to 5, respectively." https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#log-levels

Comment: So if I have a crash with no log using :debug?

Comment: It could be a crash that was totally irrecoverable so that rails was not able to log anything. You'll have to work your way down the last file known to run with breakpoints.